# Shell Scripting ssh execution of commands

Tags: linux, shell, scripting

I have no idea, how to execute this specific combined shell script command via ssh on a remote device.

```
#!/bin/bash

cmd=""
command="restart"

case "$command" in
    restart)
        cmd+="pkill -f fileA.py;"
        cmd+="python3 -u fileA.py >> fileA.log &"
        ;;
    *)
        echo "Unknown command"
esac


cmd=$(ssh root@foobar $cmd)
```

The error that occurs is:

`pkill -f fileA.py;python3 -u fileA.py >> fileA.log &
 pkill: invalid user name: fileA.py`

I know that the whole string is interpreted as one command, but that's not what I want to achive.

I appreciate any help.

Answer (score 0):

Are you sure you pasted the right code? That pkill error messages comes from using the `-u` or
`-U` options. Please check that first.

---

Next, your lack of quotes is causing you problems. After the shell substitutes the variables, you have this:

```
cmd=$(ssh root@foobar pkill -f fileA.py;python3 -u fileA.py >> fileA.log &)
```

So you're killing the process on the remote system, and launching it on the local system.

I think you really need this:

```
case "$command" in
    restart)
        cmd="pkill -f fileA.py; nohup python3 -u fileA.py >> fileA.log & disown"
        ;;
    *)
        echo "Unknown command"
esac


cmd=$(ssh root@foobar bash -c "$cmd")
```

`nohup` and `disown` allow the backgrounded process to keep running after the shell exits.